# JQuery is not working on eclipse

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to JQuery and developing a mavenized dynamic web application with eclipse.  I downloded JQuery and put the folder under webcontent and refering to it with `src` tag.

Below is the code snippet:

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/app/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
 $("#hh").hide;
 alert("OK");
 
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" id="hh" value="here">
</body>
</html>
```

However I don't see the outcome on the server.

Comment: Needs parens at end of `$("#hh").hide()`?

Comment: Isn't that what https://api.jquery.com/hide/ is *supposed* to make happen?

Comment: thats correct but atleast the alert should have worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the `reference path` to the file `(src)` is correct and that you have `permissions to read` it.

Try this,

1. Created a `test.js` file, only with this line of code  `alert("this
   work!");`
2. Put the `test.js` in your folder `App`, same place when you
   have your `jquery.js`
3. Make the reference in your code `<script
   type="text/javascript" src="/app/test.js"></script>`

If you can see the `alert("this work!")` now you know that your reference is ok, if you do not see, something you are doing wrong.

Comment: Thanks so much. I with your comment i was able to figure out the mistake was with the refernce path used in (src), I just modified to:

Comment: src="app/jquery-3.2.1.js"